# Writing PMD ruleset for XML file

Tags: xml, xpath, pmd

How to write a pmd xpath ruleset for my following XML.
I googled a lot but not able to write the ruleset for this xml content.

XML:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.hi"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name="com.example.imageencryption.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

1) I have to find the action tag with the condition that it has attribute android:name and its value is set to my said value.

2) I have to find the uses-sdk tag and find the android:minsdkversion with some fixed value.
    Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about pmd, but if you meant to translate the 2 requirements into Xpath expression, this answer may help you in a way.

> 1) I have to find the action tag with the condition that it has attribute android:name and its value is set to my said value

```
//action[@android:name='your desired value here']
```

> 2) I have to find the uses-sdk tag and find the android:minsdkversion with some fixed value

This point isn't very clear. Following xpath returns the `android:minsdkversion` attribute :

```
//uses-sdk/@android:minSdkVersion
```

But if you meant to get `<uses-sdk>` with the condition that it has attribute android:minsdkversion and it's value is set to a fixed value, following xpath will do :

```
//uses-sdk[@android:minSdkVersion='fixed value here']
```

Comment: Hi, actually i tried these xpath rule in PMD, but it's not finding the element in the xml.